# porque me sale [object HTMLInputElement]?

Tags: javascript, html

lo que yo queria pregutarles es porque me sale [object HTMLInputElement] y como podria solucionarlo.

Este es mi codigo:

```js
// esta funcion detecta cuando preciono enter en el input
function enter(msg) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {

    // si dectecto el enter entonces envia lo que se habia
    // escrito en el input dentro de un label

    document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML = msg;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Para probar el codigo escribe algo en el input y luego dale enter</p>
<input type="text" id="in" onkeypress="enter(this)">
<div><label id="cont">---</label></div>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar :)

Comment: es por el ```this```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con this estás haciendo referencia am input, que es un elemento html, de ahí el resultado que obtienes. Si quieres que aparezca el contenido del input, accede a la propiedad value del input: this.value.

Comment: muchas gracias, ya se lo añadi y si se soluciono :)